# Gradlew - Task 'clean' not found in the root project

Tags: gradle, gradlew

When I try to run the command `./gradlew clean install` I recieve the error message `Task 'clean' not found in the root project 'projectname'`

Tried multiple things including adding `apply plugin: 'base'`, but nothing worked so far.

I was wondering what I am doing wrong.
Wasn't able to post the code in this message, so here is a hastebin link with it. https://hastebin.com/uvuxiniwev.bash

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? Your linked code is not self-contained and when I make it work by removing some things, the `clean` task works for me.

Comment: This error could also happen when executing `gradlew` from a directory other than the root directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

clean task comes from the plugin java for this you may have to add

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

inside your project, since you already have it you can try deleting any cache or you can use a wrapper pointing to local path(can be downloaded from gradle repo ) like `distributionUrl=../../../build/tools/gradle-4.10.3-bin.zip` in gralde-wrapper.properties